# How to convert a string type column to list type in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'URL_domains':[['wa.me','t.co','goo.gl','fb.com'],['tinyurl.com','bit.ly'],['test.in']]})
```

Here the column URL_Domains has got 2 observations with a list of Domains.

I would like to know the length of each observations URL domain list as:

```
df['len_of_url_list'] = df['URL_domains'].map(len)
```

and output as:

[image]

That is fine and no issues with above case and

In my case these list observations are treated string type as below:

[image]

When i execute the below code with string type URL domain it has shown the below output:

[image]

How to make a datatype conversion from string to list here in pandas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`, because [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) is bad practice:

```
import ast

df['len_of_url_list'] = df['URL_domains'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
df["URL_domains"] = df["URL_domains"].apply(eval)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: @jezrael nice didnt know it, thx